# Crystal doubling up on t's

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I've written a vb.net application to populate a Crystal report and output it to PDF.  The problem is that every text box in which I have the letter "t" is being printed out to the PDF as "tt".  eg, instead of "customer", it prints "custtomer".  The design time layout is perfect.  And this only happens with text boxes on the report; value fields that contain the t character print out correctly.
Any idea where I should be looking to solve this?

Comment: That is really... odd. (I don't have an answer, I just wanted to say that is really odd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is some or other Font issue.  In the printer setup for the report I selected the "No Printer" option, and the problem has gone away.  Try figure that one out!

Answer (score 2):

Out of interest, what font are you using? I've experienced exactly the same with the Calibri font.  At the moment, the only way I've managed to get around it is to replace the font with something similar looking.

Comment: gee I don't recall what font it was set to at the time, sorry, but your mention of Calibri does ring a bell...

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem with Crystal Reports using Calibri font. It shows double t instead of single. However **the issue resolved by changing the font.**

Happy Coding :)